# I got an exception : Could not determine type for com.english.learn.entity.Forms. Why?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I got an exception while executing the program :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.english.learn.entity.Forms, at table: words, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(forms)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:486) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:347) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:466) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
... 110 common frames omitted
```

Class Word:

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "words")
public class Word {
    @Id
    private String infinitive;
    private Forms forms;
    private ArrayList<String> generalTranslate;
    private ArrayList nounsTranslate;
    private ArrayList adjectivesTranslate;
    private ArrayList stativeTranslate;
    private ArrayList pronounsTranslate;
    private ArrayList numeralsTranslate;
    private ArrayList verbsTranslate;
    private ArrayList adverbsTranslate;
    private ArrayList collocationsTranslate;
    private ArrayList sentencesTranslate;
    private ArrayList rootWordsTranslate;

    public Word() {
    }

    public Word(String infinitive, Forms forms, ArrayList<String> generalTranslate) {
        this.infinitive = infinitive;
        this.forms = forms;
        this.generalTranslate = generalTranslate;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "word_users",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "word_id")})
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
}
```

class Forms:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Forms {

    String firstSecondSimple;
    String firstSecondSimpleTranscriptionBreatish;
    String firstSecondSimplePronunsiationBreatish;
    String firstSecondSimpleTranscriptionAmerican;
    String firstSecondSimplePronunsiationAmerican;

    String thirdSimple;
    String thirdSimpleTranscriptionBreatish;
    String thirdSimplePronunsiationBreatish;
    String thirdSimpleTranscriptionAmerican;
    String thirdSimplePronunsiationAmerican;

    String past;
    String pastTranscriptionBreatish;
    String pastPronunsiationBreatish;
    String pastTranscriptionAmerican;
    String pastPronunsiationAmerican;

    String participleOne;
    String participleOneTranscriptionBreatish;
    String participleOnePronunsiationBreatish;
    String participleOneTranscriptionAmerican;
    String participleOnePronunsiationAmerican;

    String participleTwo;
    String participleTwoTranscriptionBreatish;
    String participleTwoPronunsiationBreatish;
    String participleTwoTranscriptionAmerican;
    String participleTwoPronunsiationAmerican;

    public Forms() {
    }

    public Forms(String firstSecondSimple, String firstSecondSimpleTranscriptionBreatish, String firstSecondSimplePronunsiationBreatish, String firstSecondSimpleTranscriptionAmerican, String firstSecondSimplePronunsiationAmerican, String thirdSimple, String thirdSimpleTranscriptionBreatish, String thirdSimplePronunsiationBreatish, String thirdSimpleTranscriptionAmerican, String thirdSimplePronunsiationAmerican, String past, String pastTranscriptionBreatish, String pastPronunsiationBreatish, String pastTranscriptionAmerican, String pastPronunsiationAmerican, String participleOne, String participleOneTranscriptionBreatish, String participleOnePronunsiationBreatish, String participleOneTranscriptionAmerican, String participleOnePronunsiationAmerican, String participleTwo, String participleTwoTranscriptionBreatish, String participleTwoPronunsiationBreatish, String participleTwoTranscriptionAmerican, String participleTwoPronunsiationAmerican) {
        this.firstSecondSimple = firstSecondSimple;
        this.firstSecondSimpleTranscriptionBreatish = firstSecondSimpleTranscriptionBreatish;
        this.firstSecondSimplePronunsiationBreatish = firstSecondSimplePronunsiationBreatish;
        this.firstSecondSimpleTranscriptionAmerican = firstSecondSimpleTranscriptionAmerican;
        this.firstSecondSimplePronunsiationAmerican = firstSecondSimplePronunsiationAmerican;
        this.thirdSimple = thirdSimple;
        this.thirdSimpleTranscriptionBreatish = thirdSimpleTranscriptionBreatish;
        this.thirdSimplePronunsiationBreatish = thirdSimplePronunsiationBreatish;
        this.thirdSimpleTranscriptionAmerican = thirdSimpleTranscriptionAmerican;
        this.thirdSimplePronunsiationAmerican = thirdSimplePronunsiationAmerican;
        this.past = past;
        this.pastTranscriptionBreatish = pastTranscriptionBreatish;
        this.pastPronunsiationBreatish = pastPronunsiationBreatish;
        this.pastTranscriptionAmerican = pastTranscriptionAmerican;
        this.pastPronunsiationAmerican = pastPronunsiationAmerican;
        this.participleOne = participleOne;
        this.participleOneTranscriptionBreatish = participleOneTranscriptionBreatish;
        this.participleOnePronunsiationBreatish = participleOnePronunsiationBreatish;
        this.participleOneTranscriptionAmerican = participleOneTranscriptionAmerican;
        this.participleOnePronunsiationAmerican = participleOnePronunsiationAmerican;
        this.participleTwo = participleTwo;
        this.participleTwoTranscriptionBreatish = participleTwoTranscriptionBreatish;
        this.participleTwoPronunsiationBreatish = participleTwoPronunsiationBreatish;
        this.participleTwoTranscriptionAmerican = participleTwoTranscriptionAmerican;
        this.participleTwoPronunsiationAmerican = participleTwoPronunsiationAmerican;
    }
}
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: Like Word class is an Entity , Forms also need to be an Entity.  Please add @Entity annotation to Forms class.

Comment: I add this annotation, but it didn't help to me.

Answer (score 0):

I added this annotation to class form:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Forms forms;
```

And edited class form like that:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "forms")
public class Forms {

    @Id
    private String firstSecondSimple;
```

And it works.